# How do I use trait bound in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am going to use `generic` to pass A<B<C>>>> and Z<A<B<C>>>> to a function as one type. But I don't know how to implement `trait bounds` for this. The detail are as follows.

`http` service and `https` service each have listener and poll for accept. When an accept request comes in, `handle_request()` is called to process the request.

The `http` and `https` request processing methods are the same, but in the case of `https`, `TlsService` is additionally implemented to include `tls` processing. As a result, it has the following structure:

```
pub type RawRequest = HttpService<AccessLog<RouteService<CorsService<ProxyService>>>>;

pub struct Services {
    http_service: Arc<RawRequest>,
    https_service: Arc<TlsService<RawRequest>>,
    http_accept_service: AcceptService,
    https_accept_service: AcceptService,
}

...

fn handle_request<S>(stream: TcpStream, accesslog_sender: crossbeam_channel::Sender<String>, http_service: S) {
    let connection = NewConnection {
        stream,
        service_builder: ServiceBuilder::new(),
    };

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        ACCESSLOG_SENDER
            .scope(accesslog_sender, async move {
                if let Err(_e) = http_service.call(connection).await {
                    // TODO: write error
                };
            })
            .await;
    });
}

handle_request(stream, accesslog_sender, services.http_accept_service.clone());
handle_request(stream, accesslog_sender, services.https_accept_service.clone());
```

#### Question

I am going to use generic to call the same function for different types of Service.

```
fn handle_request<S>(
    stream: TcpStream,
    accesslog_sender: crossbeam_channel::Sender<String>,
    http_service: S,
) {
      ...
}
```

But I get a trait bound error.

```
error[E0599]: no method named `call` found for type parameter `S` in the current scope
```

I'm new to Rust and I'm struggling with `generic` and `trait bound`. Please help me how to write

Comment: Have you read https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-01-syntax.html#in-function-definitions and especially the last paragraph of the section?

Comment: Rust cannot assume that as `http_service` you are going to pass a struct that implements `call` function. You have to declare it using trait bound: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/bounds.html, see also how to do it using where: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/where.html

Comment: also, it was would be easier if you could share with us minimal example with dependencies - I couldn't find `call` function here: https://docs.rs/http-service/0.5.0/http_service/trait.HttpService.html, maybe you use other crate

Answer (score 1):

When you use a generic type like `S` rust will not make any assumptions about that type (expect that it has a compile time known size). Therefore you cannot really do anything on that type. For the compiler there is no way to know that a `call()` method exists.

This is different from how C++ handles generics where you would get long and hard to read compiler errors when using a type for `S` which does not have all the functionality used by the generic function.

The solution in Rust is a `trait`. Lets suppose both your http and https service have a `call` function. You can then write a trait (or more likely use one from the library your using) which says that these types have a `call` method. You can then use this trait as a `trait bound` in your function like this: `handle_request<S : Name_of_the_trait>`

This tells the compiler to only use types as a substitute for `S` which implement `Name_of_the_trait` and therefore you can call all the functions of this trait on `S`.

I guess you should read more about traits and it should become apparent what you should do in detail.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-00-generics.html